# TCP клиент-сервер как реализовать передачу данных без краша сервера?

Tags: c#, tcp

Вот сервер:

```
namespace Server
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Запуск сервера....");
            var address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener tcpListener = new(address, 13400);
            tcpListener.Start();
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Сервер запущен.");
            try
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Слушаем клиента на порту: 13400");

                while (true)
                {
                    // Ожидание новых подключений
                    using TcpClient tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    // Проверка что клиент подключился
                    if (tcpClient.Connected)
                    {
                        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Подключился новый клиент: ");
                        await ProcessRequest(tcpClient);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Остановка сервера...");
                tcpListener.Stop();
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Сервер завершил работу!");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }

        static async Task ProcessRequest(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            using NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
            string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            await writer.WriteLineAsync($"'{line}' получил");
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот клиент:

```
namespace Client
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Подключение клиента к серверу...");
            using TcpClient tcpClient = new("127.0.0.1", 13400);
            if (tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Клиент подключён к серверу.");
            }
            string line;
            await Console.Out.WriteAsync("Напишите что-нибудь на сервер: ");
            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "")
            {
                using NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                using StreamWriter writer = new(stream);

                await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
                await writer.FlushAsync();

                using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
                string answer = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Сервер ответил: {answer}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1 - От клиента не доходят записи на сервер (текст просто не приходит, просто пишет в клиенте: "`Сервер ответил`")
2 - После двух неудачных попыток подключиться к серверу, сервер просто крашится.
3 - После закрытия клиента, сервер останавливается, как избежать остановки?
4 - Как мне организовать постоянное получение новых клиентов и их имена (кто подключился) с ip адресом?
5 - Что я не правильно реализовал в коде?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скажем так, чтобы реализовать сервер, способный параллельно принимать и отправлять сообщения нескольким клиентам, не висеть и обрабатывать ошибки подключений, то придется написать немного больше кода.

Я не буду расписывать решение подробно, но вот простой TCP сервер, умеющий принимать и передавать текстовые сообщения, поддерживая соединения с большим количеством клиентов одновременно. Здесь реализовано эхо, грубо говоря, что сервер принял, то назад и отправляет клиенту.

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 13400;
        Console.WriteLine("Запуск сервера....");
        using (TcpServer server = new TcpServer(port))
        {
            Task servertask = server.ListenAsync();
            while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "stop")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Остановка сервера...");
                    server.Stop();
                    break;
                }
            }
            await servertask;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

class TcpServer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TcpListener _listener;
    private readonly List<Connection> _clients; // это пул подключений, нужен чтобы нормально отключить всех подключенных при остановке сервера
    bool disposed;

    public TcpServer(int port)
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        _clients = new List<Connection>();
    }

    public async Task ListenAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            _listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Сервер стартовал на " + _listener.LocalEndpoint);
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Подключение: " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint + " > " + client.Client.LocalEndPoint);
                lock (_clients)
                {
                    _clients.Add(new Connection(client, c => { lock (_clients) { _clients.Remove(c); } c.Dispose(); }));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Сервер остановлен.");
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(TcpServer).FullName);
        disposed = true;
        _listener.Stop();
        if (disposing)
        {
            lock (_clients)
            {
                if (_clients.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Отключаю клиентов...");
                    foreach (Connection client in _clients)
                    {
                        client.Dispose();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Клиенты отключены.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ~TcpServer() => Dispose(false);
}

class Connection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TcpClient _client;
    private readonly NetworkStream _stream;
    private readonly EndPoint _remoteEndPoint;
    private readonly Task _readingTask;
    private readonly Task _writingTask;
    private readonly Action<Connection> _disposeCallback;
    private readonly Channel<string> _channel;
    bool disposed;

    public Connection(TcpClient client, Action<Connection> disposeCallback)
    {
        _client = client;
        _stream = client.GetStream();
        _remoteEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
        _disposeCallback = disposeCallback;
        _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
        _readingTask = RunReadingLoop();
        _writingTask = RunWritingLoop();
    }

    private async Task RunReadingLoop()
    {
        await Task.Yield(); // https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1422205/373567
        try
        {
            byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[4];
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesReceived = await _stream.ReadAsync(headerBuffer, 0, 4);
                if (bytesReceived != 4)
                    break;
                int length = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(headerBuffer);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                int count = 0;
                while (count < length)
                {
                    bytesReceived = await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, count, buffer.Length - count);
                    count += bytesReceived;
                }
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine($"<< {_remoteEndPoint}: {message}");
                await SendMessageAsync($"Echo: {message}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Клиент {_remoteEndPoint} отключился.");
            _stream.Close();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Подключение к {_remoteEndPoint} закрыто сервером.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name + ": " + ex.Message);
        }
        if (!disposed)
            _disposeCallback(this);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($">> {_remoteEndPoint}: {message}");
        await _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
    }

    private async Task RunWritingLoop()
    {
        byte[] header = new byte[4];
        await foreach(string message in _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(header, buffer.Length);
            await _stream.WriteAsync(header, 0, header.Length);
            await _stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
        disposed = true;
        if (_client.Connected)
        {
            _channel.Writer.Complete();
            _stream.Close();
            Task.WaitAll(_readingTask, _writingTask);
        }
        if (disposing)
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ~Connection() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Чтобы остановить сервер, надо написать `stop` в консоль. Обратите внимание на пул подключений. На самом деле, когда вы останавливаете TcpListener, это никак не влияет на уже подвлюченные TCP клиенты, оно только прекращает прием новых подключений. То есть клиентов надо отсоединять отдельно, что я и сделал.

А вот клиент, практически одинаковый класс `Connection` с сервером, но чуть попроще, я только выкинул лишнее.

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int port = 13400;
        Console.WriteLine("Запуск клиента....");
        try
        {
            using TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port);
            using Connection connection = new Connection(tcpClient);
            Console.WriteLine($"Подключен к серверу: {port}");
            while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input.Length == 0)
                    break;
                await connection.SendMessageAsync(input);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

class Connection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TcpClient _client;
    private readonly NetworkStream _stream;
    private readonly EndPoint _remoteEndPoint;
    private readonly Task _readingTask;
    private readonly Task _writingTask;
    private readonly Channel<string> _channel;
    bool disposed;

    public Connection(TcpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _stream = client.GetStream();
        _remoteEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
        _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
        _readingTask = RunReadingLoop();
        _writingTask = RunWritingLoop();
    }

    private async Task RunReadingLoop()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[4];
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesReceived = await _stream.ReadAsync(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
                if (bytesReceived != 4)
                    break;
                int length = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(headerBuffer);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                int count = 0;
                while (count < length)
                {
                    bytesReceived = await _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, count, buffer.Length - count);
                    count += bytesReceived;
                }
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine($"<< {_remoteEndPoint}: {message}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Сервер закрыл соединение.");
            _stream.Close();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Подключение закрыто.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name + ": " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($">> {_remoteEndPoint}: {message}");
        await _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
    }

    private async Task RunWritingLoop()
    {
        byte[] header = new byte[4];
        await foreach (string message in _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(header, buffer.Length);
            await _stream.WriteAsync(header, 0, header.Length);
            await _stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
        disposed = true;
        if (_client.Connected)
        {
            _channel.Writer.Complete();
            _stream.Close();
            Task.WaitAll(_readingTask, _writingTask);
        }
        if (disposing)
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ~Connection() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Чтобы остановить клиент, надо ввести пустую строку, нажать Enter. Реализация грубовата, но для примера передачи данных сойдет.

---

Вывод в консоль.

Сервер

```
Запуск сервера....
Сервер стартовал на 0.0.0.0:13400
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:60040 > 127.0.0.1:13400
<< 127.0.0.1:60040: привет
>> 127.0.0.1:60040: Echo: привет
Клиент 127.0.0.1:60040 отключился.
stop
Остановка сервера...
Сервер остановлен.
Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...
```

Клиент

```
Запуск клиента....
Подключен к серверу: 13400
привет
>> 127.0.0.1:13400: привет
<< 127.0.0.1:13400: Echo: привет

Подключение закрыто.
Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...
```

Еще обратите внимание, что канал соединения полнодуплексный, то есть прием и передача могут вестись одновременно, это тоже реализовано здесь и на клиенте, и на сервере.

Собственно, задача этого ответа - показать, на что способны `TcpListener` и `TcpClient` при правильном использовании.

P. S. `[STAThread]` если вы не запускаете окно и не работаете с COM объектами, вам не нужно.

Comment: Прекрасный пример. Только вы не упомянули что для реализации нужно ещё дополнительно скачать с Nuget  `System.Buffers` и `System.Memory` и вместе с этим в методе сервера `RunWritingLoop` показывает ошибку на `ReadAllAsync`. 
P.S: Работаю не в `netCore`, а на `Net.Framework 4.0 - 4.7` 
Можно ли использовать стандартными средствами решение данных проблем? (Спасибо!)

Comment: @Rudnight на .NET Framework 4.x этот код без доработок работать не будет. Зачем вы используете такой древний фреймворк? Про него забыть уже давно нужно. Создайте проект под .NET 6, и никаких NuGet пакетов ставить не нужно будет. К тому же производительность сервера в .NET 6 будет сильно выше, чем на старом фреймворке. Все средства, использованные в решении полностью стандартные, просто некоторые из них недоступны на старых фреймворках.

Comment: я понимаю что все переходят на новинки и прочее)) Но на данном моменте сижу на 19-ой студии хD где только эти фреймы установлены) Воот.

Comment: @Rudnight это уже давно не новинки, .NET 6 полгода назад вышел, а .NET 5 - полтора. 19 студия все это поддерживает, запустите установщик и проставьте галочки, он доустановит вам недостающие компоненты. Делов 5 минут. Так же .NET 6 SDK можно установить с сайта Microsoft. Выше написанный код на .NET 5 тоже будет хорошо работать. Короч, если проблема только в этом, то это не проблема.

Comment: @Rudnight удалось разобраться?

Comment: чуть позже напишу) Пока немного занят другими делами. Но тема с TCP меня прям затронула, хочу её познать получше, на хороших примерах.