# Приложение клиент-сервер C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, tcp

Делаю лабораторную, нужно сделать приложение клиент-сервер в виде чата. Само по себе приложение готово, но я не могу понять как сделать кнопки "disconnect" у приложения клиента и "Stop server" у приложения сервера, чтобы они корректно завершали работу приложений и закрывали каналы соединения. В моем коде при использовании этих кнопок приложение вылетает. Буду рад любой помощи.

Вот код:

**Приложение сервер**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace server
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int n = 0;
        int port = 8888;
        static TcpListener listener;
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        bool ListenerCheck = true;
        bool ServerIsStarded = false;



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
            if (ListenerCheck == true)
            {
                listener.Start();
                ServerLog.Items.Add("The server is running...");
                Thread listenThread = new Thread(() => listen());
                listenThread.Start();
                ListenerCheck = false;
                ServerIsStarded = true;
            }
            else Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ServerLog.Items.Add("The server has already been started.")));
        }

        public void listen()
        {
            while (ServerIsStarded)
            {
                try
                {
                    client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ServerLog.Items.Add("A new client is connected")));
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(() => Process(client));
                    clientThread.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ServerLog.Items.Add(ex.Message)));
                }
            }
        }

        public void Process(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            TcpClient client = tcpClient;
            try
            {
                stream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] data = new byte[64];
                while (true)
                {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (stream.DataAvailable);
                    string message = builder.ToString();
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ServerLog.Items.Add(message)));
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => counter()));
                    data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ServerLog.Items.Add(ex.Message)));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Dispose();
                    stream.Close();
                if (client != null)
                    client.Dispose();
                    client.Close();
            }
        }

        private void stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServerIsStarded = false;
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
                stream.Close(300);
            }
            if (client != null && client.Connected)
            {
                client.Dispose();
                client.Close();
            }
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.Stop();
                ServerLog.Items.Add("The server was stopped.");
                ListenerCheck = true;
            }
            else Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ServerLog.Items.Add("The server was not started")));
        }

        void counter()
        {
            countm.Text = Convert.ToString(n = n + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

***Приложение клиент***

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System;


namespace Client
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int outmessage = 0;
        int inmessage = 0;
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        int port = 8888;
        string address = "127.0.0.1"; 

        public void Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient(address, port);
                stream = client.GetStream();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ClientLog.Items.Add("The connection is established.")));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ClientLog.Items.Add(ex.Message);
            }
            if (client != null)
            {
                Thread listenThread = new Thread(() => listen());
                listenThread.Start();
            }
        }

        void listen()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[64];
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (stream.DataAvailable);
                    string message = builder.ToString();
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ClientLog.Items.Add("Server: " + message)));
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CountIn()));
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ClientLog.Items.Add(ex.Message)));
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.Dispose();
                stream.Close();
                client.Dispose();
                client.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = Message.Text;
            message = String.Format("{0}: {1}", Name.Text, message);
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            if (client != null && client.Connected)
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                countout.Text = Convert.ToString(outmessage = outmessage + 1);
            }
            else Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ClientLog.Items.Add("The connection was not established.")));
        }

        void CountIn()
        {
            countin.Text = Convert.ToString(inmessage = inmessage + 1);
        }

        private void Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                client.Dispose();
                ClientLog.Items.Add("Сonnection closed.");
            }
            else Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ClientLog.Items.Add("The connection was not established.")));
        }
    }

}
```

**И на всякий случай код разметки xaml:**

**Для сервера:**

```
<Window x:Class="server.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:server"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Server" Height="426.703" Width="311.989" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="757*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="ServerLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="278" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
        <Button x:Name="start" Content="Start server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,340,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="start_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="stop" Content="Stop server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,340,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Click="stop_Click"/>
        <Label Content="Server log:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label Content="Number of &#xD;&#xA;messages:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,-2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" FontSize="9"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="countm" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10"/>
        <Label Content="In:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" FontSize="10"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Для клиента:**

```
<Window x:Class="Client.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Client" Height="435" Width="508.607" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="ClientLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" Margin="10,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="473" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
        <Label Content="Client log:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="10,318,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="473" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="Send" Content="Send" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,368,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="1" Click="Send_Click"/>
        <Label Content="Message:&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,292,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="55,263,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label Content="Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,259,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Height="28" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="Connect" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,263,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="23" Grid.Row="1" Click="Connect_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Disconnect" Content="Disconnect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="408,263,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="23" Grid.Row="1" Click="Disconnect_Click"/>
        <Label Content="Number of &#xD;&#xA;messages:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="362,-3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" FontSize="9"/>
        <Label Content="In:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="423,-2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="8" Height="23"/>
        <Label Content="Out:&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="417,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="8" Height="23" Width="25"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="countin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="8"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="countout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,15,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" FontSize="8"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567