# Как передавать "разношерстные" данные по TCP?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, tcp

Мне нужно использовать TCP протокол. От сервера могут поступить два вида данных: команда (начинается со знака '/', далее имя и доп данные), либо целый файл. Читаю данные от сервера таким образом:

```
public byte[] GetData(TcpClient client)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] fileSizeBytes = new byte[4];
        int bytes = stream.Read(fileSizeBytes, 0, 4);
        int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileSizeBytes, 0);

        int bytesLeft = dataLength;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];

        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (bytesLeft > 0)
        {
            int curDataSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, bytesLeft);
            if (client.Available < curDataSize)
                curDataSize = client.Available;

            bytes = stream.Read(data, bytesRead, curDataSize);

            bytesRead += curDataSize;
            bytesLeft -= curDataSize;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Мне кажется немного не правильным решением, преобразовывать каждый раз все к строке и проверять, содержит ли она команду. В идеале, я бы хотел иметь две разные функции чтения (под строку и под целый файл). Также, есть идея, отвести первые несколько байт (допустим 8) под 'тип' информации, читать их сначала и уже после решать как обрабатывать дальнейшие байты. Возможно я изобретаю велосипед и есть более простое решение?

Comment: Очень просто,  первый передаваемый байт - тип пакета (файл\команда\что то еще\и еще\....) второй - 5 байты - размер данных, 6-{размер} - данные. Универсально для любой системы :) и удобно

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, фрагмент кода, который я привел, является рабочим, если я правильно его понимаю, то stream.Read(fileSizeBytes, 0, 4); читает первые 4 байта (ведь мы только что получили поток, в котором лежат данные), значит с 1-4 хранится размер данных?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, все понял, это же зависит от моей реализации отправки данных. Спасибо за совет!)

Comment: В этом фрагменте ожидается "размер-данные, размер-данные...", нет "тип пакета". Тут не хватает чтение байта с "тип пакета", да и вот так `if (client.Available < curDataSize)` делать не нужно. И нужно проверять что bytes>0 (признак конца потока) - иначе просто повиснет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TCP клиент-сервер как реализовать передачу данных без краша сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1384647/373567)

В этом примере в заголовек передается только длина пакета. Но рядом с ней можно передавать тип пакета. В зависимости от типа вызывать требуемый обрабочик полученных данных.

```
public enum MessageType : byte
{
    Text = 0,
    File = 1
}

class MessageHeader
{
    public MessageType Type { get; }
    public int Length { get; }

    public MessageHeader(MessageType type, int length)
    {
        Type = type;
        Length = length;
    }

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[5];
        result[0] = (byte)Type;
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(result.AsApan()[1..], Length);
        return result;
    }

    public static MessageHeader FromArray(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer)
    {
        return new MessageHeader((MessageType)buffer[0], BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(buffer[1..]));
    }
}
```

Использовать это можно как-то так.

```
MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.FromArray(bytes);
switch (header.Type)
{
    case MessageType.Text:
        // ...
        break;
    case MessageType.File:
        // ...
        break;
}
```

```
MessageHeader header = new MessageHeader(MessageType.File, 12345);
byte[] headerBytes = header.ToArray();
```