# При вызове хранимой процедуры в программе ,первый её вызов возвращает данные вызова предыдущей использованной хранимой процедуры

Tags: c#, sql, сокет

Пишу приложение - чат, что-то на подобии telegram desktop на минималках.
Реализовано все это путем написания клиентской и серверной части.
Серверная часть общается с клиентской с помощью Socket, а с базой данных через вызовы хранимых процедур using System.Data.SqlClient;

Распознавание команд сервером происходит при помощи тэгов

В приложении постоянно появляется ошибка, что при вызове одной хранимой процедуры, при первом ее вызове она выдаст данные последней использованной хранимой процедуры

Класс для работы с БД:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleChatServer
{
    class Database_work // класс для работы с sql сервером
    {
        readonly SqlConnection _connection; //объект соединения sql только для чтения        
        //Конструктор------------------------------
        public Database_work()
        {
            this._connection = new SqlConnection("Server="+Configuration.SQL_Address_global+"\\" + Configuration.SQL_Exemp_name_global + ";" + "User Id=" + Configuration.SQL_User_ID_global + ";" + "password=" + Configuration.SQL_Password_global + ";" + "initial catalog=" + Configuration.SQL_Catalog_global + ";"); // Формирование строки подключения 
        }
        //-----------------------------------------
        public string SP_ADD_USER(string user_name,string password) //добавление пользователя в БД  возвращает 1 при успешном добавлении и 0 если такой пользователь существует      
        {                       
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SP_ADD_USER";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Connection = _connection;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_NAME", user_name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", password);           
            string result = "0";
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {                  
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                    
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        if (result == "1")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Пользователь: " + user_name + " зарегистрирован в системе с паролем: " + password);  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Пользователь: " + user_name + " неудачная попытка регистрации в системе с паролем: " + password);
                        }
                    }
                    _connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                } 
            }           
            return result; //Возвращение результата
        }
        public string SP_USER_AUTORIZATION(string user_name, string password) //Возвращает строку результат_выполнения(1/0)&айди_пользователя&username
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "SP_USER_AUTORIZATION";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_NAME", user_name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            command.Connection = _connection;
            string result = "0";
            string Result_fulfillment; //переменная для результата выполнения 1 - столбец
            string user_id; // переменная для user_id - 2 столбец
            string username;// переменная для username  - 3 столбец
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {                    
                    //SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Result_fulfillment = (string)reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        user_id = (string)reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        username = (string)reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        result = Result_fulfillment + Configuration.znak_separator + user_id + Configuration.znak_separator + username;
                        if ((string)Result_fulfillment == "1")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Пользователь: " + username + " успешно авторизован в системе!");
                        }
                        if ((string)Result_fulfillment == "0")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Пользователь: " + username + " неудачная попытка авторизации!");
                        }
                    }
                    _connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        public  string[] SP_SEARCH_USER(string user_name) //Поиск пользователей в бд //ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ ТАБЛИЦУ МАССИВОМ
        //id&username|
        //id&username|
        //id&username|
        //id&username|
        //id&username|          
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SP_SEARCH_USER";       
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", user_name);
            //command.Connection = _connection;
            string[] result;
            result = new string[2];
            result[0] = "0"; // предварительное зануление результатов для возвращения в случае ошибки
            result[1] = "0";
            List<string> formed_result_list = new List<string>();        //Вспомогательный список для формирования ответа   
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if(reader.HasRows) // если есть стороки
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            formed_result_list.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString() + Configuration.znak_separator + reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                            //Формируем ответ от хранимой процедуры в последовательность удобную для передачи по сети, в нашем случае значения столбцов разделяются & а записи в таблице разделяются |
                        }                                              
                    }
                    _connection.Close();
                    result = new string[formed_result_list.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == result.Length - 1)
                        {
                            result[i] = formed_result_list[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result[i] = formed_result_list[i] + Configuration.znak_separator_strok_from_bd;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());                
                }
                

            }
            
            return result; //Возвращение результата
        }
        public string SP_ADD_DIALOG_PARE(string id_user_from_client, string id_target_user) //добавление пользователя в БД  возвращает 1 при успешном добавлении и 0 если такой пользователь существует      
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SP_ADD_DIALOG_PARE";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_ID_INICIATOR", id_user_from_client);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_ID_DIALOG_START", id_target_user);   
            command.Connection = _connection;
            string result = "0";
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {                   
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();                        
                    }
                    _connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return result; //Возвращение результата
        }
        public string[] SP_SEARCH_DIALOG_PAIR(int user_id) //Вывод id и username всех пользователей с кем есть диалог
        //id&username
        //id&username
        //id&username
        //id&username
        //id&username
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SP_SEARCH_DIALOG_PAIR";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_ID_INICIATOR", user_id);
            command.Connection = _connection;
            string[] result;
            result = new string[2]; // В случае отсутствия диалога с пользователем так как возвращает два столбца, вернет два пустых столбца
            result[0] = "0";
            result[1] = "0";
            List<string> formed_result_list = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {                    
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows) // если есть стороки
                    {                        
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            formed_result_list.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString() + Configuration.znak_separator + reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                            //Формируем ответ от хранимой процедуры в последовательность удобную для передачи по сети, в нашем случае значения столбцов разделяются & а записи в таблице разделяются |
                        }
                    }
                    _connection.Close();
                    result = new string[formed_result_list.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == result.Length - 1)
                        {
                            result[i] = formed_result_list[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result[i] = formed_result_list[i] + Configuration.znak_separator_strok_from_bd;
                        }
                    }
                    command.Parameters.Clear(); // очистка параметров sql
                    command.Dispose();//Освобождаем все ресурсы SQL(Параметры) 
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return result; //Возвращение результата
        }




        public bool connection_check()
        {
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                _connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Клиентская часть(С учетом передачи данных по сокетам):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WFChat
{
    static class Network // класс для работы с сетью
    {       
        static int port = Remote_Server_Network_config.SERVER_PORT;
        static string address = Remote_Server_Network_config.SERVER_IP;
        static TcpClient client = null;
        static NetworkStream stream = null;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void connect_initialization()
        {
            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient(Network.address, Network.port);
                stream = client.GetStream();
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Ошибка подключения к серверу."+" Код ошибки: "+ex.ErrorCode+", Повторить подключение?", "Сервер недоступен!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                if(res == DialogResult.Retry)
                {
                    Network.connect_initialization();
                }
                if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {                 
                    Environment.Exit(1); // Завершение программы и передача ОС код завершения 1                    
                }
            }            
        }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         

        public static string[] Send_command_ret_str(string Tag, string Message,bool is_table) 
           /*
           метод отправки сообщения(с упраляющими тэгами) на сервер
           и получение ответа c большим буфером
           Возвращает строковый массив, если сторона БД возвращает 1 элемент, то массив длинной 1
           Если БД возвращает несколько элементов, то массив с таким количеством элементов 
           */
        {                        
            string Tag_message = Tag_data_work.TagFormed(Tag, Message);
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {                   
                    // ввод сообщения
                    string message = Tag_message;
                    // преобразуем сообщение в массив байтов
                    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                    // отправка сообщения на сервер
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);                  
                    // получаем ответ от сервера (отработка хранимой процедуры)
                    //-------------------------------------------------------
                   if (is_table == false) //не таблица false
                    {
                        data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        int bytes = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                        }
                        while (stream.DataAvailable);
                        //-------------------------------------------------------
                        if (builder.ToString().Contains(Remote_Server_Network_config.znak_separator))// Формирование массива при возвращении нескольких переменных
                        {
                            string[] server_answer = Tag_data_work.input_data_formed(builder.ToString());// ответ от сервера
                            return server_answer;// возвращение ответа
                        }
                        else // Формирование ответа при одной возвращаемой переменной
                        {
                            string[] server_answer = new string[1];
                            server_answer[0] = builder.ToString();
                            return server_answer;// возвращение ответа
                        }                   
                    }
                    if (is_table == true) // таблица
                        // ОТДЕЛЬНО ДЛЯ ТАБЛИЦ СДЕЛАНО НА БУДУЮШЕЕ ДЛЯ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ ПЕРЕДАЧИ БОЛЬШИХ ТАБЛИЦ
                    {
                        data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        int bytes = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                        }
                        while (stream.DataAvailable);
                        string[] server_answer = builder.ToString().Split(Remote_Server_Network_config.znak_separator_DB_table);
                        return server_answer;
                        // В случае возвращения табличных данных вернётся массив, элементом которого будет строка, данные столбцов которых будут разделены &
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                string[] error_answer = new string[1];
                error_answer[0] = "0";
                return error_answer;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Какие есть предположения, что в коде может быть не так при вызове хранимых процедур , что данные с одной процедуры переходят единоразово на вызов очередной?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали? Пишите логи прохождения данных на клиенте и сервере, смотрите, в чем именно проблема. В сети или в базе. У меня к этому коду слишком много вопросов, которые стоило бы устранить до того как начинать разбираться с указанной проблемой. Но они все не касаются того что вы спрашиваете, например [этот момент вообще упустили](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects), в блоке `finally` выполняете ненадежный код, `AddWithValue` - [зло](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Нужно больше сведений о результатах отладки.

Comment: По поводу клиент-сервера - [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567).