# Реализация TCP асинхронного подключения на игровом движке Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, tcp

Всем привет. Не могу правильно реализовать систему подключения. Задача следующая:
Нужно создать асинхронное подключение, чтобы срабатывал метод только в том случае, когда был ответ от сервера NetworkStream.ReadAsync. этот метод приостанавливает выполнения вторичного потока и ожидает приход от сервера пакета(ов). Проблема в том, что Unity не многопоточная. И когда я открываю вторичный поток на чтение, мне даёт ошибку как раз о том, что я пытаюсь использовать API Unity не в главном его потоке. Думал реализовать собственный сигнализированный метод, с помощью: ManualResetEvent. Но понятия не имею, как проверить пришли ли данные или нет. Через IEnumerator не подходит. При задержке в 1 секунду. Происходят артефакты сети. К примеру пакет пришел, и он должен сразу же выполнится. А IEnumerator будет ещё ждать секунду. Как лучше поступить? Как с помощью Task.Factory.StartNew синхронизировать поток с главным потоком Unity? Для не кастыльного общения с API Unity

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий клиент-сервер я представляю примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567).

Но у вас не одна проблема, для начала разберитесь с сетью. TCP - протокол с гарантированной доставной, но нет гарантии, что принимаемый пакет прилетит за раз. То есть пакет может быть фрагментирован. Решается это только передачей и проверкой длины пакета (реализовано в примере по ссылке выше).

Далее, чтобы передавать и принимать данные из рабочего потока, вам нужна реализация Producre/Consumer, то есть потокобезопасная коллекция, исполняющая роль буфера. В .NET Framework 4.x я знаю только одну такую - BlockingCollection, возможно в самой Unity есть и другие средства, я с движком не работал, знаю только сам .NET. И не используйте `Task.Factory.StartNew`, используйте `Task.Run`.

Есть еще например для приема данных неблокирующая ConcurrentQueue, в рабочем потоке вы например можете класть в нее принятые пакеты, а в каком-нибудь FixedUpdate() проверять, есть ли там что-нибудь, и если есть - забирать.

Но можно и без async/await обойтись, как говорится, старыми дедовским способами.

**Отправка**

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

class SendExample : MonoBehavior
{
    // byte[] просто для примера, здесь может быть любой тип.
    private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _sendQueue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

    void Start()
    {
        Task.Run(SendLoop);
    }

    private void SendLoop()
    {
        foreach (byte[] data in _sendQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            SendToServer(data); // вызов метода вашей сетевой части из рабочего потока
        }
    }

    private void StopSend() // этот метод надо вызвать перед остановкой работы скрипта
    {
        _sendQueue.Complete();
    }

    private void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        _sendQueue.Add(data);
    }
}
```

**Получение**

```
class ReceiveExample : MonoBehavior
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> _receiveQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (_receiveQueue.TryDequeue(out byte[] data))
        {
            // получены новые данные
        }
    }

    private void Receive(byte[] data) // этот метод надо вызвать из рабочего потока, получающего данные из сети
    {
        _receiveQueue.Enqueue(data);
    }
}
```

Это по сути самая простая Poducer/Consumer развязка между потоками. К примеру по ссылке в начале этого ответа ее должно быть не сложно прикрутить. И цель этой развязки - не допустить тормозорв игры, пока работает сеть.

Comment: Я кажется понял. Можно узнать оптимизированный метод чтение пакетов в FixedUpdate? Чтобы игру не тормозило

Comment: @MRXIT он же есть в ответе.

Comment: А что вызывает Receive? Можно пример? Мне сама запись нужна, как можно отлавливать?

Comment: @MRXIT Receive - это способ забросить данные в Unity поток. Откуда хотите, оттуда и вызывайте. У вас же где-то данные из сети приходят, вот там и вызывайте. Можете пнреименовать Receive а SendToUnity например, если так понятнее.

Comment: Аааа, так и думал. Все, теперь понял. Спасибо огромное, вы очень сильно помогли!)