# C# System.Net TcpClient, NetworkStream Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующие подключение

Tags: c#, tcpclient, websokets, tcplistener

Есть клиент, он отправляет на сервер клавишу преобразованную в byte, сервер принимает эту клавишу и вносит её в список. После выполнения int bytes = stream2.Read(KeyBuffer,0,_m) выдает исключение "Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующие подключение", однако bytes содержит корректное число полученных кнопок, также буффер содержит полученные клавиши. Но соединение почему то разрывается сразу после этой строки. Часа 4 сижу над этой ошибкой, вообще не пойму, ассихронку не юзаю.

```
public static void Send(Keys key)
{
    stream2.WriteByte((byte)key);
}
const int _m = 20;
static byte[] KeyBuffer = new byte[_m];

public static LanKeyPress PressKey;
public static void ReciveKeys()
{
    try
    {
        int bytes = stream2.Read(KeyBuffer,0,_m);//Тут разрывается соединение
        
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            PressKey((Keys)KeyBuffer[i]);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)KeyBuffer[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

[image: Исключение]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос больше не актуален! Решение:

```
public static void ReciveKeys()
{
    Task<int> task = stream2.ReadAsync(KeyBuffer,0,_m);
    
    task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(()=>
                                  {
                                    for(int i = 0; i < task.Result; i++)
                                    {
                                        PressKey((Keys)KeyBuffer[i]);
                                        Console.WriteLine((Keys)KeyBuffer[i]);
                                    }
                                  });
}
public static void Send(Keys key)
{
    stream2.WriteAsync(new byte[]{(byte)key},0,1);
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужно синхронно выполнить, просто вместо `ReadAsync` используйте `Read`, зачем вообще эти навороты, если вы вызываете асинхронный метод и тут же блокируете вызывающий поток в ожидании его завершения? Это называется синхронное блокирующее ожидаие асинхронного метода или sync-over-async, то есть убийство асинхронной природы метода в целом. Очень плохая практика.

Comment: Пример правильного клиент-сервера я вам выше кинул, жаль, что вы отказались разбираться. :( начните хотя-бы с изучеия шаблона Producer/Consumer, многое прояснит.