# Литература, статьи, уроки по клиент-серверному взаимодействию в C#?

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, tcp, сетевое-программирование

Всегда боялся TCP\UDP, все было неинтуитивно и очень непонятно, но потом пришлось столкнуться с этим, и успехи добавили мотивации, но вопросов все еще много. Хочется понять, как правильно описывать классы для взаимодействия по сети, как одним сервером обрабатывать множество клиентов, как передавать большие данные частями и т.д. Т.е. самые азы, но не голая теория типа "открыли сокет", а именно архитектура и паттерны.
Что можно почитать, чтобы лучше понимать, как правильно писать клиент-серверные приложения?

Comment: Да может лучше родную микрософтовскую документацию копать начать? Там и примеры и теория и всё, что нужно. И в соотнесении с конкретными версиями фреймворка. А то у них бывает вообще всё меняется и читать про старые технологии смысла уже нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567 вот пример