# Большое количество переключений контекста в программе на .NET на Linux машине

Tags: c#, linux, .net, io

Заметил, что при работе своей программы, написанной на C# (.NET 6), происходит большое количество переключений контекста. Программа в основном занимается приемом/передачей данных по сети. Для теста решил написать простое клиент-сервеное приложение.

На Linux сервере запустил вот такой код:

```
TcpClient client = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

try
{
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        if (stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) == 0)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch { }
```

На своем Windows ПК запустил такой код:

```
TcpClient client = new();
client.Connect(_endPoint);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(1024);

try
{
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
catch { }
```

На сервере установлен Munin, который на пике показывал 15000 переключений контекста (context switches) и прерываний (interrupts) в секунду. Если сервер и ПК поменять ролями, то есть сервер отправляет данные, а ПК принимает, переключений контеста было всего лишь 500, а прерывания подсткакивали до 4000.
[image: Munin]

Моя программа использует асинхронные операции ввода-вывода, а тестовая программа использует синхронные операции в одном основном потоке. Если переписать тестовую программу с использованием асинхронных оперций, то, думаю ситуация в лучшую сторону не изменится. Например, Nginx обсулживает больше соединений и значительно больший трафик, но такого большого количества переключений контекста не происходит. Почему это происходит именно в .NET и как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Во-первых, `using` надо использовать для `IDisposable` объектов. Во-вторых, что касается асинхронного кода для работы с TcpClient - то [вот он](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567). Так что не надо теории, тестируйте на практике. В однопоточке никто серверы не делает. В-третьих, источник проблемы вероятно неоптимизированный код и создание кучи потоков без надобности (пул потоков существует же, верно?), но эти нюансы вы оставили в тайне.

Comment: В тестовой программе я написал максимально простой код, который показывает, что дело не в нюансах и неоптимизированном коде. Именно этот код, как показано на скриншоте, вызывает 15000 переключений контекста в секунду.

Comment: Так у вас цикл `while (client.Connected)`, вы уверены, `stream.Read` блокирует поток, а не пролетает мимо? Я всякого видел с TcpListener, и зачем вы бросаете исключение, когда можно просто `break` вызвать? Всплеск происходит сразу или когда клиент подключится, или после того как отключится, когда именно? Вы только здесь не диспозите потоки данных или на рабочем сервере тоже? Давайте посмотрим на воспроизводимый пример, а не на вырезки кода, и пишите сразу асинхронно. Вы попробовали запустить пример из ссылки выше? Он такой же эффект дает или нормально работает?

Comment: Всплеск происходит когда начинают передаваться данные. Они беспрерывно передаются с максимально возможной скоростью. В случае ошибки или отключения клиента программа завершается, поэтому Dispose в данном случае не использую. В примере выше указан весь код тестовой программы, вырезана только инициализация _tcpListener и _endPoint. Ваш пример не запускал, так как там нужно вручную передавать данные.

Comment: Так-то вроде логично: пришёл пакет в буфер карты - прерывание - копирование в буфер ядра и декапсуляция - копирование данных в доступное для программы место - переключение контекста для работы программы. Это я объясняю, почему у вас так много (на самом деле нет) прерываний. Почему "у них" так мало - понятия не имею.