# C# асинхронное прослушивание сокета в проекте WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, сервер, сокет

#### Идея

Существует некоторое приложение (WinForms), к которому необходимо подключить что-то вроде сервера. Я пытался засунуть в данное приложение консоль, но после некоторого потраченного времени на изучение данного вопроса, пришел к выводу, что этого делать не стоит, а будет лучше подключить новую форму и там обрабатывать все что нужно (если есть комментарии по этому поводу, я внимательно вас читаю).

#### Многопоточность

Так вот, самая первая проблема возникла в ходе проб и ошибок, когда запущенное окно блокировало родительское на этапе прослушивания клиента. Ну и собственно в голову пришло изучение и использование многопоточности, а т.к. я не являюсь его знатоком, то тут начало возникать куча проблем. Опишу 2 из них, которые значительно усложняют мою задачу:

1. **(опционально, вы можете пропустить данную проблему)** В форме-сервере находится RixhBoxText, который выводит промежуточные данные о записях или принятых данных. При попытке запустить метод следующим способом: `Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen())); myThread.Start();` выкидывает ошибку о том, что нельзя изменять RichBoxText в других потоках, кроме самого потока формы.
2. В данной [статье](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/sockets/socket-services), вроде, нашел решение своей проблемы.
   Создание сокета происходит так:

```
private Socket listener = null;
private IPEndPoint ipPoint = null;

private void Server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create listener with console app
    this.ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
    this.listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(ipPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bufferAfterLoad = ex.Message;
    }
    //if normal connected, say about it
    newMainForm.ServerOn();
}
```

Далее, после выводы формы, запускаем метод прослушки:

```
private void Server_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bufferAfterLoad != null)
    Print(bufferAfterLoad);
    Listen();
}

async private void Listen()
{
    Print($"Connected to {serialNum} device!"); 
    try
    {
        var handler = await listener.AcceptAsync(); // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫДАЕТ ОШИБКУ!!!
        while (true)
        {
            //Receive message.
            var buffer = new byte[1_024];
            var received = await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
            var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);

            var eom = "<|EOM|>";
            if (response.IndexOf(eom) > -1 /* is end of message */)
            {
            Print($"Socket server received message: \"{response.Replace(eom, "")}\"");

            var ackMessage = "<|ACK|>";
            var echoBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ackMessage);
            await handler.SendAsync(echoBytes, 0);
            Print($"Socket server sent acknowledgment: \"{ackMessage}\"");

            break;
            }
            // Sample output:
            // Socket server received message: "Hi friends !"
            // Socket server sent acknowledgment: "<|ACK|>"
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Print(ex.Message);
        Print("Wait for closing...");
        Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**Ну и собственно сама ошибка:** *Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру "e" из "Socket.AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)".*

---

#### PS

Если есть какие-то замечания или идеи по данной ситуации, я внимательно вас читаю :)
Дочитавшим до конца - спасибо за терпение!

Comment: Используйте TcpListener вместо Socket, там внутри уже всё как надо сделано. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567

Comment: Не используйте UI приложения в качестве сервера, используйте консольное, и лучше реализуйте управление сервером из другого приложения, либо из самой консоли. А то пытаетесь смешать несмешиваемое.