# Не получается добавить элемент в listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

При вызове функции listview1.Items.Add(item) ничего не происходит. Все остальное работает корректно. Прилагаю максимально упрощенный код всего проекта. Весь проект с формой и прочим dropmefiles.com/y8mhU

```
using Server.Helper;
using SuperSimpleTcp;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;


namespace Server
{
    public partial class Sever : Form
    {
        private ListViewColumnSorter lvwColumnSorter;

        public bool isserveractive;

        public SimpleTcpServer server;

        public Sever()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Main(string ip2dotport)
        {
            isserveractive = true;
            server = new SimpleTcpServer(ip2dotport);
            server.Events.ClientConnected += ClientConnected;
            server.Events.ClientDisconnected += ClientDisconnected;
            server.Events.DataReceived += DataReceived;
            server.Start();
        }

        public static void dothsgwithrecievd(byte[] codedb)
        {
            try
            {
                // do something with bytes
                var just2call = new Server.Sever();
                just2call.mainwork(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(codedb.ToArray()));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        public void mainwork(string part_of_the_link)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Do something
                    Thread th = new Thread(() => formiruem("string", "string"));
                    th.Start();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void formiruem(string path, string part_of_the_link)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do something
                string[] row = { "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "string" };
                // не добавляеться в listview
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        public void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod("dothsgwithrecievd");
            mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { e.Data });
        }

        static void ClientConnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        static void ClientDisconnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну пока тут вообще не понятно, что вы хотите и зачем этот код вообще нужен, что значит "ничего не происходит". Я только вижу, что у вас есть непонятно откуда взявшийся `listView1`, который не нужен и нигде не используется. Можно предположить, что у вас что-то напутано с потоком, но ничего конкретного вы не показали.

Comment: listView1 объявлен в Sever.Designer.cs . Весь проект с формой и прочим https://dropmefiles.com/y8mhU

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567