# Странная реакция локального сервера на приходяще запросы с параллельно работающих клиентов. Сервер на C#

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, tcp, tcp-ip

Имеется сервер, когд которого представлен ниже. Сам код еще плох, но тем не менее для одного клиента все работает хорошо, я бы даже сказал, что работает хорошо и для двух, но с 1 но:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Task listeningTask = new Task(Listen);
            listeningTask.Start(); 
            listeningTask.Wait(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Close(); // Закрываем сокет
        }
    }
    private static void Listen()
    {          
        try
        {
            IpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);
            sListener.Bind(IpEndPoint);
            sListener.Listen(5);
            while (true)
            {
                Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
                EndPoint remoteIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0); 

                string data = null;

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

                data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                if (data.IndexOf("<TheEnd>") > -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Сервер завершил соединение с клиентом.");
                    continue;
                }
                string[] massive = data.Split();

                switch (getCommand(massive))
                {
                    case "searchINN":
                        //здесь код
                        break;
                    case "fullDB":
                        //здесь код
                        break;
                    default:
                        //здесь код
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Close();
        }
        
        
    }
```

Собственно перейцдем к "но". Когда к серверу подключаются сразу несколько людей, ничего не предвещает беды. Первый человек шлет запрос и получает ответ, но вот когда второй шлет запрос, то ответ он не получит, пока первый человек не отошлет новый запрос на сервер. То есть

1 - ничего не вводит
2 - Ввел команду
Сервер - молчит(хотя он уже всю информацию получил и мог бы отдать ее)
1 - вводит команду и получает ответ
2 - получает ответ на предыдущую команду, которая до этого зависла и не приходила обратно

Comment: Есть такой пример, вдруг пригодится https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567

Comment: Главная проблема при получении данных, что сокет не гарантирует полное наполнение буфера или даже нет гарантии, что пакет ляжет в буфер целиком. Чтобы это контролировать, надо реализовать контроль целостности данных на уровне вашего собственного протокола. Так же нет контроля открытых соединений. То есть вам с такой логикой надо либо на UDP переходить, либо учиться держать соединения в разных потоках. То есть поймали подключения - отправили обработку в поток, и так далее, а у вас всё синхронное, информация об открытых подключениях теряется (см. пример пр ссылке, там коллекция подключений)

Comment: То есть вы теряете подключение вместе с `handler`, один раз прочитали и забыли, а должен быть цикл до того пока сокет `handler` не закроется. Он и отвечает за открытое соединение.

Comment: Кстати не запускайте таскопотоки через конструктор и Start, это жуткое легаси, запускайте так: `Task task = Task.Run(() => Метод());`