# Передача данных по TCP через интернет

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать передачу данных между двумя программами, установленными на разных ПЭВМ по протоколу TCP через интернет. (то есть айпишники публичные, не локальные). Как поднять локальный TCP сервер я знаю, но когда речь идет о сетевом взаимодействии, увы... Что делаю не так или может я о чем-то не догадываюсь, помогите.

СЕРВЕР:

```
IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
using Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, 
ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(ipPoint);
socket.Listen(100);
```

КЛИЕНТ:

```
            using var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                //тут указал условный публичный айпишник сервера
                await socket.ConnectAsync("94.103.226.200", 8888); 
                IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999);
                MessageBox.Show($"Подключение к {socket.RemoteEndPoint} установлено");
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Не удалось установить подключение");
            }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567

Comment: @aepot спасибо, классный пример сервака, для локального чата я и сам писал подобное, но это отлично работало у меня в условиях закрытой локальной сети компании, теперь же я имею желание использовать это для интернет пространства, и когда в клиенте вместо 127.0.0.1 я указываю публичный айпишник сервера 94.103.224.226 - мне выдает ошибку, что не может установить соединение... Не знаете что не так? может быть фаервол, может быть вообще не туда я смотрю... Нет опыта в таком вопросе?

Comment: @AlexF у меня оба ПО работают от роутера. Пробовал даже один ПЭВМ запитать от модема (телефона), а второй от Lan (другого оператора) что бы разные айпи были, но нет. Я подозреваю, что тут прикол в фаерволе может быть или других настройках ОС, но хз в чем. Десктоп телега например разве не по TCP передает инфу? Сетевой администратор на обоих концах я, ну если не считать операторов связи))

Comment: @AlexF спасибо большое, но дело, как я и думал, было в другом. надо было настроить NAT на роутере

Answer (score 0):

Код данного ПО вполне рабочий, действительно, но вот достучаться до сервера, который развернут на ПК, который в свою очередь имеет выход в инет только через роутер, не вариант без дополнительных танцев. Существует такая штука как NAT, которая отвечает за переадресацию трафика. Публичный айпишник - это айпишник не ПК, а роутера, а роутер уже внутри сети раздает всем свои айпишники по типу 192.168.0.1 и т.д. Так вот что бы все было ок - нужно зайти в настройки роутера -> настройки NAT -> добавить порт (в моем случае был 13400) и настроить переадрисацию на ПК с сервером. Вуаля!

Comment: Именно так, где-то даже об этом я здесь уже писал, но не могу найти. Это называется переадресация портов (Port Forwarding).

Comment: @aepot да, спасибо, вы и Alex направили меня в нужное русло!