# Как организовать отпаравку сообщений между клиентом и сервером через сокеты. c#

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, tcp

Как организовать отправку личных сообщений через сокеты. Одним пакетом? Термин "Пакет" подходит для данного случая? Пишу на c#

###### Пример:

Нужно отправить текстовое сообщение. В этом случае я посылаю нечто вроде
`message;private;text;id_получателя;текст сообщения`
Далее сервер разделяет его по точке с запятой и обрабатывает этот "Пакет" (если это можно так назвать) и посылает нужному клиенту.

Ещё интересуют ньюансы, по типу отправления больших данных. (Если буфер будет мал)

На сколько мой подход правилен?

Comment: Протокол какой? TCP? UDP? Почему голый сокет, а не что-то более высокоуровневое?

Comment: @aepot, По началу хотел разобраться с сокетами =) Протокол TCP

Comment: Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: @aepot, можно на tcp  сразу? Я переделаю вопрос. у меня вопрос больше обобщенный, чем конкретно связанный с сокетами. Я изменю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зря вы взялись за голые сокеты без понимания сути протокола TCP и вообще без понимания особенностей передачи данных по сети.

Самая главная ошибка здесь в том, что вы думаете, что вам придет в считывающий метод ровно столько данных, сколько вы отправили. Пакеты при передаче по сети могут фрагментироваться, получен быть может не весь пает, а только его часть. UTF-8 это не однобайтовая кодировка данных, и отправляя байты в декодер, вы просто можете сломать сообщение, разбив какой-то символ посередине. Следовательно никакой перекодировки делать нельзя до тех пор, пока пакет не будет получен полностью.

А как узнать, что пакет получен полностью используя только протокол? А никак, вы никак не узнаете длину пакета если явно не передадите ее со стороны отправителя. То есть используя транспортный протокол TCP, вам следует реализовать поверх него свой собственный протокол приложения, как например реализован HTTP и прочие протоколы уровня приложения.

Для создания такого протокола, нужно создать такую сущность как **пакет**, пакет семантически состоит из 2 частей - заголовок и данные. Заголовок содержит в первую очередь информацию о количестве байт данных, потому что получая пакет и не зная этой информации, вы не сможете его корректно принять. Также заголовок может содержать и другую информацию, например тип пакета или другие метаданные, позволяющие этот пакет правильно принять. Здесь уже вы сами как создатель протокола решаете, что должен содержать заголовок.

```
пакет
{
    заголовок,
    данные
}
```

Самый простой заголовок - это просто длина пакета, число размером 4 байта в начале пакета (`int`). Считав его вы сможете далее продолжать читать ответ до тех пор, пока не получите обещанное отправителем число байт. Каким-то таким образом оно и будет работать.

Вторая сущность, с которой следует познакомиться в рамках обучшения TCP - это **подключение**. Подключение устанавливается клиентом к серверу, и через это установленное подключение можно передать пакет. Установка самого по себе подключения - очень дорогостоящая операция и времени, так как она требует выполнения целокй кучи действий, например опрос DNS серверов, выбор типа шифрования и так далее. Поэтому для экономии ресурсов принято после принятия или передачи данных подключение не разрывать.

То есть устанавливаете подключение однократно и передаете последовательно пакеты туда-сюда до тех пор пока клиент не захочет отключиться, либо оно не будет разорвано по каким-то другим техническим причинам, например из-за обрыва связи.

```
подключение
{
    пакет -->,
    пакет <--,
    пакет <--,
    ...
    пакет <--,
    пакет -->
}
закрытие подключения
```

Начните освоение протокола TCP с классов `TCPListener` и `TCPClient`. В них уже реализована правильная низкоуровневая работа с сокетами, чтобы избежать ошибок на этом уровне.

Примеры есть в ранее данных мной ответах: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+TCPListener

Comment: не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на пример с пакетами? интересно очень, но найти у вас не могу...

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER По ссылке же все примеры с пакетами. Без пакетов никак. Хотя-бы [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567) обратите внимание на `int bytesReceived = await _stream.ReadAsync(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);` - тот самый заголовок 4 байта.

Comment: могу я с вами связаться как-нибудь. Не понимаю немного. Там в примрере клиент отправляет сообщение потом пишется "Клиент ендопинт отключился." но он по факту подключен же? и список клиентов при каждом сообщении увеличивется.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER нет, со мной никак не связаться. Изучайте разные примеры, не зацикливайтесь на одном. Примеры могут содержать недочеты, и даже какие-то ошибки. Смысл здесь не в получении готового кода, а в том чтобы понять, что это вообще такое и как оно работает. Разберетесь - сможете написать свой понятный код.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER обратите внимание на делегат в строчке `_clients.Add(new Connection(client, c => { lock (_clients) { _clients.Remove(c); } c.Dispose(); }));`. он удаляет отключенный клиент из списка.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER `_disposeCallback(this);` вот же он вызываестя. Если до сюда не дошло, значит подключение не было закрыто.

Comment: извиняюсь, недоглядел. А как правильно будет обрабатывать сообщения у клиента? нужно писать отдельный метод для RunReadingLoop в котором обрабатывать входящие сообщения?

Comment: а как их передавать в рамках wpf MVVM если таска приватная да ещё и ничего не возвращает........

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER Читайте содержимое Channel в UI потоке `await foreach` цикл. Разбирайтесь, не всё сразу будет понятно, это нормально. Другие примеры смотрите тоже. Про асинхронное программирование почитайте что-нибудь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146041/discussion-between-yava43developer-and-aepot).

Comment: я тут немного разобрался. подскажи как организовать передачу других хедеров. Которые обозначаю тип сообщения и кому. не могу никак это в твоем коде реализовать.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER это уже не мой код, а ваш. :) Для простоты, можете представить что кроме длины пакета в заголовке больше ничего нет. Всё остальное - данные. Что туда положите, то там и будет. А вообще еще раз повторю, я дал ссылку на много разных примеров, изучайте, там всё есть.